# How to create multirow & multicolumn bitmap layout on Blackberry

Tags: layout, blackberry, java-me

I have 8 bitmap and i want to put 4 of them to the first row, rest to the second row...

Can you help me to use TableLayoutManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the BlackBerry developer knowledgebase article:
[Create a rich UI layout with TableLayoutManager](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-rich-UI-layout-with-TableLayoutManager/ta-p/445299)

It's a pretty simple class to work with, if you're familiar with RIM's thought process (lol)